# Closing Notepad++ tabs on closing application

Tags: notepad++

Is it possible to make Notepad++ close all open tabs when it is shut down?

Currently when a new file is opened with Notepad++ all previously open tabs (and of course the files open in those tabs) are reopened.

Comment: Related question: [Where are the paths of last opened files](http://superuser.com/questions/240146/where-are-the-paths-to-the-files-open-in-notepad-last-open-tabs-stored). Useful in case you cannot open Notepad++ because there is a huge file in this list.

Comment: Answer by @user321756 is now the CORRECT answer for the latest version

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`Settings > Preferences > Backup >` Uncheck `Remember the current session for next launch`

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I knew that this had to be possible, but for somereason never thought to get under MISC. Now to decide if I actually want to change the behaviour...

Comment: I can never decide which I want either. I need a program which reads my mind and only shows the previous session if I plan to work on those files. :)

Comment: An interesting option would be to have it remember the session if you hold down a modifier key while closing the program or something. Or, like Firefox can, just prompt you when you close it.

Comment: The problem with that is that I often don't know if I will want it until the next time it starts. I think it would work better if it restored the session if you hold down a modifier key *while it starts up*. (Hmm, I may have to make some sort of experimental app for this...)

Comment: @Dan: just close the documents (Ctrl+Shift+W) when you start NP++, if you decide don't want them open.

Comment: This option has moved since this answer was written. See [user321756's answer](http://superuser.com/a/751785/383046) for the new location.

Answer (score 47):

As an update for anyone that was looking for the answer to this as I was, the latest version of Notepad++ (v. 6.6.1) has this option under:

**Settings** → **Preferences** → **Backup** → Check "Remember current session for next launch"

Comment: This should be voted up. The chosen answer is now outdated.

Comment: The OP wanted this option OFF, not ON.  This answer is incorrect, it should be "Uncheck", which makes it a duplicate of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

In latest version uncheck

```
Settings > Preferences > MISC. > Remember the current session for next launch
```

[image: Remember the current session for next launch]