# Where are the paths to the files open in Notepad++ (last open tabs) stored?

Tags: windows, notepad++

*i.e. todo.txt, medical.txt, etc.*

I looked at XML files in `C:\Program Files\Notepad++`, but to no avail.

Comment: I have the same question. I have the portable app Notepad++.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
%APPDATA%\notepad++\config.xml
```

or perhaps

```
%APPDATA%\notepad++\session.xml
```

By the way, if you want to know how I found this out, I fired up [Sysinternals ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), set a filter on the ProcessName field to "notepad++.exe", closed Notepad++ and then ProcMon showed me which files had been accessed when I closed it.

Comment: Beat you to it by 7 seconds :P

Comment: Did I see you ninja-deleting an answer? :)

Comment: Well, if BloodPhilia really was first, I'll have to mark him as the answer.

Comment: Check out my super educational edit!

Comment: Oh man, sorry BloodPhilia!  :o

Comment: @JohnB Right, lol... XD It's ok!

Comment: On Windows XP, this is `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\session.xml`

Comment: I do not have "C:\Users".

Answer (score 7):

This location should work regardless of username or Windows version:

```
%APPDATA%\Notepad++\session.xml
```

Answer (score 4):

It's in `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\session.xml`

Comment: I do not have "C:\Users".

Comment: Typing ```%appdata%``` into the Windows search will take you to AppData.

Answer (score 2):

C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to visit below mentioned directory,this will contains all the files temporarily saved by notepad++.

`%AppData%\Roaming\Notepad++\backup`

Comment: Good answer, but on my PC `%AppData%` takes me to `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\` for some reason (instead of just `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\)

Answer (score 0):

As of v7.4.2, If you downloaded the executable (i.e. did not do a windows installation), then it would be in `<your_NPP_location>\config.xml`