# How to not show the last file when starting up Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closing Notepad++ tabs on closing application](https://superuser.com/questions/10538/closing-notepad-tabs-on-closing-application)

It's very annoying that every time Notepad++ starts, it displays the last modified file. Is there a setting to turn this feature off?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Settings->Preferences

Click on the "MISC" tab.

Uncheck the option on the bottom left: "Remember current session for next launch"

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Things have changed a bit in Notepad. I am using Notepad++ v6.6.1. 
The feature is currently available under:
Settings > Preferences > Backup > Remember current session for next launch (top right hand section)

Answer (score 14):

In Notepad++ the feature is referred to as the 'session' (all the docs you had open when you last closed it).

To disable it via Notepad++ (as noted in other answer):

`Settings -->  Preferences --> Misc. Tab --> Un-check "Remember current session for next launch"`

[image: NP++ Misc Prefs Screen]

From outside Notepad++, you can use the command-line argument `-nosession` to force NP++ to start without loading the last session:

> **-nosession** Use this parameter to launch Notepad++ without loading the previous session (the files opened in Notepad++ at the last time).
>   On shutdown, Notepad++ will not record currently opened files in
>   session.xml.

For the complete list of command-line options check out [this page on NP++'s wiki on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Command_Line_Switches).

Comment: Thanks for "-nosession" option. This can be critical when Notepad++ was closed with a very big file opened. It can take hours to start it again then.

Comment: Or if, for some reason, Notepad++ is crashing on launch :)