# Stop Session Restore in Notepad++ v6.6.7

Tags: notepad++

I like notepad++ plus but hate that by default it always remembers my last session. How can I disable it I thought it was in the misc setting but maybe I am blind but I don't see it there

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closing Notepad++ tabs on closing application](http://superuser.com/questions/10538/closing-notepad-tabs-on-closing-application)

Comment: Specifically this answer: http://superuser.com/a/751785/23133 :)

Comment: Like the strong language and totally agree :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Remember current session for next launch" is at the top of the `Backup` section starting with the v6.6 (was in `MISC.` section in earlier version).

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675202/notepad-setting-so-it-doesnt-open-old-files-from-previous-session